# How can I make my Mac shutdown a Windows PC when my UPS signals power loss?

Tags: ups

I have an APC UPS connected to my iMac that's set to shutdown after 1 minute of running on UPS power. I also have a Windows 10 PC plugged into the UPS that I'd like shut down as well. Is there a way to send a shutdown command from my Mac to the Windows 10 PC telling it to shut down as well when a power loss is detected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this SuperUser question [How can I shutdown a Windows machine remotely from OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/331039/how-can-i-shutdown-a-windows-machine-remotely-from-os-x). It recommends installing and using the `net` command:

```
net rpc shutdown -I xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -U username%password
```

You can then use a tool like [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/) to trigger the `net` command [when your UPS detects](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2013-07-08-how-to-shut-down-when-ups-power-drops/) the power failure.

[image: Shut down event when UPS drops to 30%]

I work on Power Manager, so feel free to ask technical questions.